# How can I force Rspec to not falsely think another module is nested inside the parent?

Tags: ruby, rspec, jwt

I have an issue that's appearing only when running `rspec`, my application loads and works fine locally and in production

rspec seems to think that the gem `JWT` belongs to my module `BACKBONE`

```
An error occurred while loading spec_helper.
Failure/Error: JWT.encode(payload, ENV['APP_SECRET'], 'HS256')

NameError:
  uninitialized constant BACKBONE::JWT
# ./lib/jwt.rb:6:in `encode'
# ./lib/backbone/policies.rb:7:in `<class:Policy>'
# ./lib/backbone/policies.rb:5:in `<module:BACKBONE>'
# ./lib/backbone/policies.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
# ./init.rb:10:in `load'
# ./init.rb:10:in `block in <module:CrewManagement>'
# ./init.rb:10:in `glob'
# ./init.rb:10:in `<module:CrewManagement>'
# ./init.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/spec_helper.rb:16:in `require'
# ./spec/spec_helper.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
```

files are listed in the order they are loaded into memory, it may be useful to note that I have several other applications with the same setup that are not experiencing this issue

## /spec/spec_helper.rb

```
require 'bundler'
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start

Bundler.require :default
Dotenv.load("./.env.#{(ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development')}")

require 'rack/test'
require './init'

# ...
```

## /init.rb

```
module CrewManagement
  ## ...
  Dir.glob('./lib/**/*.rb') { |file| load file }
  ## ...
end
```

## /lib/jwt.rb

```
module BACKBONE
  def self.encode(payload)
    JWT.encode(payload, ENV['APP_SECRET'], 'HS256')
  end

  def self.decode(token)
    JWT.decode(token, ENV['APP_SECRET'], true, algorithm: 'HS256')
  end
end
```

## /lib/backbone/policies.rb

```
module BACKBONE
  headers = { 'Authorization' => BACKBONE.encode(app: '...') }
end
```

Comment: I am not sure why this is happening but you can try `::JWT` which makes it resolve to the outermost level

Comment: good suggestion, wasnt successful - but I was able to get it working by using require_relative to the `/lib/jwt.rb` file for some reason

Comment: The "some reason" is not very mysterious. JWT was defined in `jwt.rb`. You hadn't loaded `jwt.rb`, so JWT didn't exist when you tried to use it and you got an error. The error said BACKBONE::JWT because you happened to be inside BACKBONE. If you had tried to use JWT inside a module called Foo the error would have said Foo::JWT, because Ruby starts looking in whatever module you're in. Once you loaded the file where JWT was defined, the error went away because JWT existed. It's not a case of RSpec or Ruby being mistaken about anything—it's a case of trying to use a module you hadn't loaded.

Comment: @JordanRunning please move your response to an answer - that was the correct solution